# Groovy Android and libgdx

Tags: android, groovy, libgdx

I'm trying to get libgdx working with Groovy for Android ([groovy-android-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/melix/groovy-android-gradle-plugin)).

I've successfully got a [test project](https://github.com/townsfolk/grooid-drop) compiling, and starting up, but when the game loads it crashes due to a missing `y` property on the [`Rectangle`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Rectangle.html) class.

When I first tried this, the game crashed when accessing the static fields of the [`Gdx`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Gdx.html) class. Eg. when I tried to access the `gl` field via `Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1)`. I solved this issue by adding `@CompileStatic` to all the classes.

However, as I've said, this doesn't seem to solve all problems.

I'm not sure if this is a groovy issue as the fields are `public` but also have getters and setters (the latter returning the Rectangle object) or an issue with the Groovy Android plugin. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Note that I know how to work around the issue by changing the broken line from: `raindrop.y -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()` to `raindrop.y = raindrop.y - 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()`, but I'd still like to know why this is breaking so I can avoid future issues.

Comment: you have this problem on other targets (e.g. desktop) too (e.g. can you be sure, that this is no general problem)?  In general you are better off using `@CompileStatic` in games and on anroid (and even more when both are in the boat) for performance (and with newer versions of gradle (since 2.1) you can apply such a transformation ofr all classes automatically)

Comment: I don't have this issue when running it under the Desktop. I understand that using `@CompileStatic` in games should be definitely be used, but even with `@CompileStatic` - seems in the android execution, it's not finding the property properly.

Comment: Do you have proguard turned on? The compilation for desktop and android should be the same. Also what version of the plugin are you using?